# Can I alias an array of structs to an array of struct members?

Tags: c++, arrays, optimization, struct, copy

I am wondering if it is possible to create/copy a "virtual" array of a specific member of a struct in another array. Let's say we have a struct

```
struct foo {
  int value;
  char character;
};
```

Now assume there is an array containing this struct `foo` and I have an operation that needs to add all `int value`'s together. This would normally be very easy with a loop adding all the values with a pointer. Problem is I am using OpenCL and need to copy an array to some device. In OpenCL this is done using

```
clEnqueueWriteBuffer(cmdQueue, buffer, CL_TRUE, 0, datasize, A, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

which will copy an array `buffer` to the device. It doesn't make sense to copy the entire array of structs, since the would take more time, because it also sends the `character`s which is not needed. It would also take up more space on the OpenCL device. Is it therefore possible to copy the "array" of `value`s from the structs directly as an array to the device?

I know I can create a new array on the host (CPU) with all the values and then copy that array to the OpenCL device, but then I would spend time copying to a local `int`-array and afterwards copy that array to the OpenCL device.

Would it be possible to copy a "virtual" array of `value`s directly from the array of `foo`-structs, containing only the `int value`s?

Please beware, that this is a very simplified example of my actual problem and would like to avoid having the `value`s in a separate array from the beginning, which the structs would then point to. I have big doubts that this is possible, and if my explanation even makes sense, but look forward to feedback!

Comment: You can still call `clEnqueueWriteBuffer` in a loop... :-/

Comment: you can iterate through the pointer and copy only the "value" in the buffer if you have array of structure. Also when you are iterating through the pointer then be aware about structure padding. you can use #pragma pack 1 to avoid extra byte used for padding.

Answer (score 2):

No.

`clEnqueueWriteBuffer` expects a contiguous container. You cannot create a "virtual" contiguous container.

> [I] like to avoid having the values in a separate array from the beginning.

At that point, you must profile and compare two implementations: one copying the array as-is with the superfluous data, and one creating a local copy of the useful data to send. Compare and choose.

Comment: Same as above, Thank you!  Didn't write the program myself, but am implementing OpenCL for it now, so would have been nice to do. Will change it to separate arrays now.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array of structs you would need a staging buffer with just the values, which is extra copies on the CPU side.

Sometimes such work is unavoidable, but if you can, it is better to have multiple arrays of continuous values. Even in pure CPU work this is frequently more efficient for the CPU cache as it avoids read/writes of unneeded members and is often easier for SIMD instruction sets like SSE.

For example you could have `int *values` and `char *chars` of the same length (prefer some type like `std::vector` or `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` though!), then the copy is easy.

Comment: Thank you. Didn't write the program myself, but am implementing OpenCL for it now, so would have been nice to do. Will change it to separate arrays now.